# Use firefox "customize" menu without a mouse

Tags: firefox, keyboard, mouse, manjaro

Firefox is the best webrowser available right now, but I've recently had the misfortune of having to use it in a context without a mouse available.

So far i've been able to use and configure it fairly effectively with vim vixen and about:config. However I can't work out how to configure the interface without a mouse. with a mouse you can hit that "customize" button and drag/drop icons in and out of the toolbar. However activating the customize menu with only a keyboard available leads to a menu which seems to be entirely mouse driven. There's no keyboard support.

Comment: I don't have a good solution for you on Manjaro right now, but if this remains unresolved, I suggest filing a bugzilla issue report.  Mozilla is very proactive about ensuring Firefox is fully accessible to everyone, and this could be something they would want to resolve right away.